# Different lighttpd rewrite rules in subirectory

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, lighttpd, subdirectory

I'm having a few issues getting rewrite rules for a specific subdirectroy (different from the webroot) and I'm at a loss as to where to put them.

/var/www/ (webroot containing WordPress)
/var/www/subdirectory (containing other app which requires it's own rewrite rules)

The below rules I for WordPress which is in the webroot dir (/var/www, or http://mywebsite.com):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "mywebsite.com" {
  url.rewrite-final = (

    # Exclude some directories from rewriting
    "^/(wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-content|gallery2)/(.*)" => "$0",

    # Exclude .php files at root from rewriting
    "^/(.*.php)" => "$0",

    # Handle permalinks and feeds
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
  )
}
```

Then I have a second app that sits in a subdirectory of the webroot (/var/www/subdirectory, or http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory) with the following rules:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "(index.php|test.php|favicon.ico)" => "/$1",
    "(css|files|img|js)/(.*)" => "/$1/$2",
    "^([^\?]*)(\?(.+))?$" => "/index.php?url=$1&$3",
)
```

What I need is for the 1st set of rewrite rules above applied to everything except the other directories in the #Excluded rule above (as well as /subdirectory) then the 2nd set of rules applied to only /subdirectory

I got the first set of rules for WordPress from a blog somewhere online any may well be not exactly what I need (in regards to matching "mywebsite.com" and could probably be simplified).

I've Googled myself out trying multiple variations (mostly just stabbing in the dark guided by random forum posts that are slightly related), but I just can't wrap my head round it.

So how would I go about having the 2nd set of rules applied to the subdirectory while maintaining the Wordpress rules for the root?

Note: I have no access to subdomains (that would be too easy).

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you want to express - I will explain what your current ruleset does.

do not use this, user rewrite-once instead

```
url.rewrite = (
```

you keep map any index.php and test.php (even foo-test.php) back to the webroot

```
"(index.php|test.php|favicon.ico)" => "/$1",
```

you rewrite any subfolder or files containing css,files,tmp or js in it's url back to the webroot

```
"(css|files|img|js)/(.*)" => "/$1/$2",
```

now this matches anything in the your webroot (no subdirs!) and keeps get requests

```
"^([^\?]*)(\?(.+))?$" => "/index.php?url=$1&$3",
)
```

**Update**
This should do it (untested)

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^/subdir/(?:index.php|test.php|favicon.ico)" => "$0",
"^/subdir/(?:.+/)?(css|files|img|js)/(.*)" => "/subdir/$1/$2", #update #2
"^/subdir/(?:/(?:.+/))?([^\?]*)(?:\?(.+))?$" => "/subdir/index.php?url=$1&$2",

"^/(wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-content|gallery2)/(.*)" => "$0",
"^/(.*.php)" => "$0",
"^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've updated the question to add some clarity (hopefully).

Basically the first set of rules need to be applied to the webroot "/" excluding certain directories (as per the line after "# Exclude..." including /subdirectory) and then have the 2nd set of rules applied only to /subdirectory.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Updated accordingly (just replace subdir with your actual directory)

Comment: This is 1/2 way working, it is rewriting the pages themselves but the css and images are not being rewritten. I have tried adding /subdir/ to the $0 in the first 2 lines but that does not appear to work.

Comment: Did you declare the css and image files properly to be treated as such? This is a common issue if you just experience styling issues. If you do have these, I am a bit puzzled what is left.
I also found a minor error above

Comment: I've applied the updated set of rules and the css/images/js are still not loading. What do you mean by declaring them?

Comment: `mimetype.assign  = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg", 
    ".png" => "image/png", 
    ".css" => "text/css" )`